# How to I can code/tool eclipse RCP plugin GUI testing

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an eclipse RCP plugin, I have completed code and some unit testing, now I want to provide the GUI testing, Do you have any ideas about what open tools/libraries I used? is it possible I can install this plugin to eclipse and perform GUI testing with codes to simulate just like end users?

Comment: You should remove the Swing tag for this question or do you have written your RCP plugin in Swing instead of SWT.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [SWTBot](http://swtbot.com/) for this task. It will help you to select widgets in a straightforward manner. You can simulate the user interaction on each widget. SWTBot is provided as Eclipse Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

SWTBot helps to do GUI testing. We actually built a framework on top of SWTBot to code GUI tests. you can also look at eclipse TPTP for recording GUI tests but it has its limitations.

http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/project_info/general/whatisTPTP.php

Answer (score 0):

Windowtester is a powerful tool from google thateliminates the need to manually create test cases to test GUIs by automating the process of GUI testing. Generated tests tend to be SWTBot or similar to SWTBot and easy to edit and automate tests. https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wintester/html/